# Как отсортировать результат parcing?

Tags: парсер, сортировка

Нужно вывести сначала наименьшие цены товаров

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


  for i in range(1, 6):
      print(f"Parsing {i} page")
      url = "https://cvetland.kz/almaty/product-category/catalog/?utm_term=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE&matchtype=b&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=!Zakaz_zvetov_|_Poisk_|_Almaty&gad=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuuHfz7CvgQMVWQkGAB0OaASIEAAYAiAAEgI1GfD_BwE{i}/"
      response = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

      names = soup.find_all("a", class_ = "question__title-link question__title-link_list")
      prices = soup.find_all("span", class_ = "woocommerce-Price-amount amount")


      for j in range(0, len(names)):
          print(names[j].text)
      for j in range(0, len(prices)):
          print(prices[j].text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставил Вам комментарии, что бы было более понятно.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = {} # словарь для сбора информации

for i in range(1, 6):
    print(f"Parsing {i} page")
    # внимательнее с URL и с перебором страниц, у вас стоял номер страницы не в том месте
    url = f"https://cvetland.kz/almaty/product-category/catalog/page/{i}/?utm_term=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE&matchtype=b&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=%21Zakaz_zvetov_%7C_Poisk_%7C_Almaty&gad=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuuHfz7CvgQMVWQkGAB0OaASIEAAYAiAAEgI1GfD_BwE%7Bi%7D%2F"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    product_items = soup.find_all("div", "product-item") # собираем все карточки на странице
    for product_item in product_items:
        title = product_item.find("h5", "item-title").text # названия
        price = product_item.find("span", "woocommerce-Price-amount amount")\
            .text.replace("₸", "").replace(" ", "").replace("\xa0", "") # цена, сразу избавимся от лишних символов
        data[title]=price # соберем данные в словарь
sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[1])) # отсортируем данные
print(dict(sorted_data)) # вывод отсортированного словаря
```

Вывод:

```
{'Клубника в шоколаде №22': '15500', 'Сирень 2': '17500', 'Lili 5': '17500', 'Букет из 17 розовых роз': '18500', 'Клубника в шоколаде №19': '18500', 'Lili 8': '19900', 'Lili 12': '21500', 'Букет из 21 розовой розы': '21900', 'Букет хризантем №3': '23500', 'Lili 13': '23900', 'Коробка «Сирень»': '25500', 'Клубника в шоколаде №17': '25500', 'Lili 9': '25500', 'Букет из 25 белых роз,': '25900', 'Букет Дуэт гортензий': '25900', 'Lili 2': '26500', 'Lili 1': '26500', 'Lili 10': '27500', 'Lili 7': '27500', 'Lili 4': '27900', 'Букет из 5 ароматных пион': '28500', 'Букет хризантем №1': '29500', 'Сирень 1': '32500', 'Букет хризантем №2': '32500', 'Lili 6': '32500', 'Lili 3': '33500', 'Букет из хризантем и роз «Леди»': '35000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 5': '35000', 'Букет хризантем №5': '35500', '31 красная роза и мерси': '35900', 'Букет хризантем №4': '35900', 'Букет хризантем №6': '37500', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 17': '40000', 'Сирень 4': '45000', 'Сирень 3': '45000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 14': '45000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 12': '45000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 6': '45000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 21': '50000', 'Корзина из 51 красной розы (Голландия)': '52900', 'Lili 11': '53500', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 19': '55000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 4': '55000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 18': '65000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 11': '65000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 20': '70000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 16': '70000', 'Букет из 101 красной розы': '79000', '101 роза нежный': '79000', 'Букет Пушистик 5': '87500', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 15': '90000', 'Букет Пушистик 2': '91900', 'Букет Пушистик 3': '95000', 'Букет Пушистик 1': '95000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 10': '105000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 8': '125000', 'Букет Пушистик 4': '145000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 9': '155000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 13': '160000', 'Букет «Бамбастик» 7': '160000'}
```